# Populating a HTML input field from a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html

I’m not sure if this is possible (hence me posting here). I’ve not been able to find any documentation on this anywhere, so I either can’t be done, or I’m an idiot and have missed something super obvious.

So it’s possible to populate the subject line of an email with a mailto link like this:

```
<a href="mailto:test@example.com?subject=Testing out mailto!">First Example</a>
```

I have a button on my website that displays under all blog posts. This button goes to my guestbook (yes, guestbooks still exist). What I’d like is to have a field on my guestbook signing form to be auto populated with the link they came from. So I know the referring link.

So, for example, if someone is reading https://example.com/post-1

When they click the “sign my guestbook” button it would automatically populate the “Post you’re responding to” HTML input field with https://example.com/post-1

Is this possible in plain old HTML? If not, what would be the best way to achieve this aim?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the Sign my guestbook button navigate to a new page ? you would actually need a small piece of JS to do this. Basically you set a variable in the global object everytime you click the button which will hold the URL in the address bar. And in the guestbook page, you just read the variable to populate the field.

Comment: It is a new page, yeah. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, a single line of javascript is all you need:

```
document.getElementById('myInput').value = document.referrer;
```

This is because:

```
document.referrer
```

tells you the URL of the page you visited which linked to the page you are visiting now.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const referringPostInput = document.getElementById('referring-post');
referringPostInput.value = document.referrer;
referringPostInput.size = referringPostInput.value.length;
```

```html
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Post you're responding to:</legend>
<input type="url" name="referring-post" id="referring-post" readonly />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: This is excellent, thanks. I’ll test when I’m back at my machine and will feed back.